# Fix bar chart spacing between bars in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm trying to create a report with a bar graph like the one shown.  I would like the space between the labels 31 and 38 represent the space between the numbers 31 and 38.

In other words, I need the places where there are arrows to have more space (or labels with zero data).

Is there some way to do this?

[image: Bar Graph with points where I need spacing to be more]

Answer (score 1):

You will need to return all x-axis values that you want to display but have a null when there is no value. The chart should still plot the x-axis points with no bar.